# Updating objects from a drop down list in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Trying to edit objects in a drop-down list. When selecting an item, `name` and `suffix` display in editable text fields; I can edit (and save) `name`, but changes to `suffix` don't stick.

Here's the JS code, the rest in on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/raffian/4kXXc/1/

```
function Domain(n){
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(n);
    self.suffix = ko.observable();
};

function DomainsViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.domains = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.newDomain = ko.observable("");
    self.selectedDomain = ko.observable();

    self.addNewDomain = function() {
        self.domains.push(new Domain(self.newDomain()));
        self.newDomain('')
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new DomainsViewModel());
```

Comment: Don't know the technical reason why it doesn't work. An alternative working solution is to remove `selectedDomain().` and replace it by placing a with binding in either tr or td `data-bind="with: selectedDomain"` http://jsfiddle.net/f42xw/

Comment: You're saying `data-bind="with: selectedDomain"` in a `<td>` sets the context for anything in that element such that I can use `name` and `suffix` without qualifying?

Comment: Yes. See this sample http://jsfiddle.net/f42xw/

Comment: Sweet! Submit that as the answer, I'll accept it, and thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know the technical reason why it doesn't work (anybody knows?)

A working solution is to remove `selectedDomain().` and replace it by placing a with binding in either tr or td elements `data-bind="with: selectedDomain"`

Sample http://jsfiddle.net/f42xw/