# Updating a KnockoutJS array on form submit

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Looking to improve user experience by having KO array update when user clicks submit button, instead of automatically as Knockout does so well. Have put together this test page on Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/HaSNd/ - but is in need of a magic touch...

JS:

```
function ViewModel() {

    var self = this;

    self.someVal = ko.observable();

    self.items = ko.observableArray([{
        someVal: "first item"
    }]);

    self.submitForm = function () {
        self.items.push({
            someVal: self.someVal()
        });
    };

    self.updateItem = function () {
        //Magic here
    };
}

var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

HTML

```
<form data-bind="submit: submitForm">
    <fieldset>
        <p><b>Add items to array:</b>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input data-bind="value: someVal" type="text" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <button type="submit" data-bind="">Add item</button>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<br />
<fieldset style="background-color: #eee; "> <b>Array summary:</b>
    <br />
    <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
        <li data-bind="text: someVal"></li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
<p><b>Update items in array manually:</b>
</p>
<form data-bind="submit: updateItem, foreach: items">
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            <input data-bind="value: someVal" />
        </p>
        <button type="submit" data-bind="">Update item</button> <button type="submit" data-bind="">Cancel</button>
    </fieldset>
    <br />
</form>
<br />
<br />
<span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></span>
```

Comment: Are you trying to setup a single click `update` for all modified items or is the update per data element? If it is per element, then I would move the `submit: updateItem` into a `click: $root.updateItem($data)` on each update button. Or you could setup a [with binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) to handle the data context for you. Example using `with binding` can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224310/updating-objects-from-a-drop-down-list-in-knockout-js)

Comment: Yes, update per data element. Not clear on the function required for "updateItem" - would it include KO's replace method to update that element in the array?

Comment: After more consideration, I developed an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/LBH6f/) of what I think you might be looking for. In order to delay/control the modification of observables, wrap the "modified" context in a nested view model.

Comment: Thanks :) Definitely heading in the right direction! Instead of the drop down, I need a list of the array items with input texts as per original please - just because each will finally contain more updatable fields in an accordion - similar to http://jsfiddle.net/72T8h/

Comment: I modified your example to include the extra "modified" state holder. See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/j23h8/).

Comment: Nice work!! Thank you so much :) :)

Comment: So I was thinking about this again. Depending on how many fields you eventually have, you'll want something a little more robust to handle any additional/new fields for `Employee`. So I setup another [example](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/VLcKc/). The modified context is stored inside each observable rather than duplicated alongside them. With the addition of the abstraction of `properties` to a function on `Employee`, any additions or modifications will easily slip into the existing code base.

Comment: That's useful because the development version will be more complex with the employee view containing an observable array of quarterly data able to be modified and saved in the same way as you've described here.