# Knockout stops updating observable after unpacking property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Just noticed some unexpected behaviour in knockout.js - Got some code that loops round an observableArray and repeats some bound HTML elements for each item in the array. One of the items is a property on a sub-object:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Contact">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Project().Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Percentage"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This renders fine on page load. But if the user performs actions that end up changing the Contact array or the items inside it, Name and Project().Name update but Percentage does not, even though stepping through shows it has the correct value.

However, if I remove the unpacked sub-object:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Contact">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Percentage"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Everything works perfectly.

What's going on here, and is there a fix better than using a computed observable or somesuch to calculate and hold my Project().Name value?

Comment: out of curiousity, does reordering affect the problem?  i.e. if Project().name is rendered last does that allow Percentage to render?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in jsfiddle? Also `<td data-bind="Percentage"></td>` etc. probably should be `<td data-bind="text: Percentage"></td>`

Comment: - Joseph - yes, it works fine if Project().Name comes last ... sroes - I'll try and put something together, but we've got a complex application and I can't always reproduce problems in a simplstic jsfiddle approximation.

Comment: I'd also be very interested to see a repro in jsfiddle.  This sounds like a possible bug or definite 'gotcha' that may be good to understand.  P.S.  I'm assuming that the `data-bind` attributes actually are using `text:`

Comment: Yes, they are using text. Working on a fiddle, but it isn't.

Comment: Hmm. As I suspected, when put in my stripped back fiddle, things work as expected :(

Comment: you might try turning on `break on all exceptions` in the browser console to see if there's an error occurring that prevents the remainder of the processing (you'll have to continue through any 'by-design' errors).  That's what it sounds like is happening - maybe not a true error, but some condition that causes the processing to abort, which is demonstrated by swapping the order of the bound elements.

Comment: Nope, break on all exceptions shows nothing new.

Comment: You should really try to repro this in a fiddle... otherwise it is almost impossible to tell you what goes wrong. However you should try create a computed as mentioned or rewriting your expression to :`<td data-bind="text: Project() && Project().Name"></td>`

Comment: Similar issue [seen here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20224310/updating-objects-from-a-drop-down-list-in-knockout-js). I added it to my favorites back when I experienced roughly the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<td data-bind="text: ko.computed(function() { return Project().Name() })"></td>
```

if you need 2-way binding, you can use writable computed